# Mysql Select дубликаты строк + оригиналы

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, как вывести все строки, в определенном столбце которого есть дубликаты + оригинал.

Стандартная конструкция, написанная на миллионах форумах, выводит **Только** дубликаты, без оригиналов.

```
SELECT * FROM `e1xc7_obj` WHERE `cat` = 'category1'  GROUP BY `obj_author` HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Допустим в строках со значением столбца "category1" есть 3 строки, где obj_author = 213. Я хочу увидеть все 3 строки, а не только два дубликата.

Comment: *Стандартная конструкция* - в общем случае приводит к ошибке, а в принципе даже когда работает - является "bad practice". *Я хочу увидеть все 3 строки, а не только два дубликата.* Посчитать количество в CTE оконной версией COUNT(), вывести те, где оно больше 1.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел изящное и элегантное решение.

```
SELECT `obj_author` FROM `e1xc7_obj` WHERE `cat` = 'category1' ORDER BY `obj_author` ASC;
```

А потом глазками 5 тысяч строк в базе данных пробегаем, и делаем что нужно.